# How can I use agda2-mode to generate patterns when I expect to see an absurd pattern?

Tags: emacs, agda, agda-mode

For example, we're proving `2 + 2 != 5`:

```
data _+_≡_ : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ → Set where
  znn : ∀ {n} → zero + n ≡ n
  sns : ∀ {m n k} → m + n ≡ k → suc m + n ≡ suc k
```

And I can manually prove it:

```
2+2≠5 : 2 + 2 ≡ 5 → ⊥
2+2≠5 (sns (sns ()))
```

But I want the pattern `(sns (sns ()))` to be generated (just like filling a hole). Are there any ways to achieve that?

I am using Emacs 25 with agda2-mode.

Comment: There is a somewhat similar [issue](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/2069#issuecomment-330351186). With this feature you could probably write `2+2≠5 (snsN ())` where `snsN` generates an appropriate number of `sns`s. Not much of automation, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so let's say you start from this configuration:

```
2+2≠5 : 2 + 2 ≡ 5 → ⊥
2+2≠5 h = {!!}
```

In this case you can use emacs' [keyboard macros](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros) because the sub-term generated by matching on `h` will also be named `h`. So using:

- `<f3>` (start recording the macro)
- `C-c C-f` (move to the hole)
- `C-c C-c h RET` (match on `h`)
- `<f4>` (record the macro)

you've recorded the action of "moving to the first goal an matching on h". You can now keep pressing `<f4>` until you reach an absurd case.

Comment: This is awesome! If a better approach doesn't appear for a day I'll set your answer as accepted :D